# What does the 1412 in Magic Kaito 1412 means?

Tags: kaito-kid

The title of the show is Magic Kaito 1412. It is based on a character from Detective Conan, Kaito Kid. In Detective Conan he is called Kaito Kid, Phantom Thief, but no 1412. If it is read in Japanese it would be Ichi Yon Ichi Ni (One Four One Two) or Sen Yon Hyaku Juu Ni (One Thousand Four Hundred Twelve). The real name of the first Kaito Kid is Kuroba Touichi. The current Kaito Kid is Kuroba Kaito, doesn't sounds like 1412 at all. So, what is this 1412 means?

Comment: 14 = KI   12 = D_ so Magic Kaito Kid

Comment: they explain it in Detective Conan manga looooooong time ago, but i forgot which chapter